# mysql link statement doesn't return records without a link

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table called Users in my database. A user can have multiple addresses, but in some cases they won't have any. My mysql link statement is only returning records which have at least one address:

```
$query = ' SELECT DISTINCT a.id FROM users as a, addresses as b' ;
$query.= ' WHERE a.id = b.userId ' ;
```

How can I alter this so that users with no addresses will still be returned?

I'm guessing theres a simple solution to this I'm just missing!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: well, in your query, you are using a join which requires both rows to be present. Can you not just query for distinct a.id from users alone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `LEFT JOIN` instead:

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.id
FROM   Users a LEFT JOIN Addresses b
        on a.ID = b.UserID
```

Comment: Cheers, thanks for the answer.. Let's say users had phone numbers as well, same thing, they may have many or none. Can two LEFT JOINs be used?

Comment: Yes. basically `LEFT JOIN` returns all records based on the records of the left table whether it has a match on the right table or not.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a `LEFT JOIN`:

```
$query = ' SELECT DISTINCT a.id FROM users as a LEFT JOIN addresses as b' ;
$query.= ' ON a.id = b.userId ' ;
```